# What accounting entries should I make for writing off a personal loan?

Tags: gnucash, double-entry, writeoffs

I loaned my father $20. This is how I recorded the transaction in GnuCash:

| Account | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Assets:Loans:Father | $20 |  |
| Assets:Banks:USD |  | $20 |

Now, I want to forgive the debt. What entries should I make in GnuCash to write off the debt? I know that the "Assets:Loans:Father" account should be credited to erase the debt, but what account should I debit to balance the credit?

| Account | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ??? | $20 |  |
| Assets:Loans:Father |  | $20 |

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd debit "Bad Debt Expense" or comparably named expense account.

Edit: I like glglgl's idea of the same account as gifts to keep number of accounts low, it's really just a matter of whether or not you want to track this sort of unintentional gift separately or not.

Comment: I didn't understand it as "unintentional", I read "Now, I want to forgive the debt." as "I don't need to, but I do it voluntarily". But at the end, it's a matter of personal opinion.

Answer (score 5):

You use the same expense account you would use for a gift.